# Value pass in AsyncTask is in Object formate in android

Tags: android

```
public class GecodeFuncation {

public static String getLatLongByURL(String requestURL) {
    URL url;
    String response = "";
    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;
            }
        } else {
            response = "";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response;
  }
}
```

I am excuting AsyncTask in this way:

```
  new GeocodeImplementation().execute("D-109 3rd floor ShakarPur Laxmi Nagar New Delhi 110092".replace(" ","%20"));
```

below is my `AsyncTask`:

```
class GeocodeImplementation extends  AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {
        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(DataEntry.this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
            String response;
            try {
                response = GecodeFuncation.getLatLongByURL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+params+"&sensor=false");
                Log.d("response",""+response);
                return new String[]{response};
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new String[]{"error"};
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String... result) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result[0]);

                double lng = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                        .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                        .getDouble("lng");

                double lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
                        .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
                        .getDouble("lat");

                Log.d("latitude", "" + lat);
                Log.d("longitude", "" + lng);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
```

When I pass address to AsyncTask then its URL becomes:

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[Ljava.lang.String;@41fff330&sensor=false

So  I am unable to get Response while it should be

http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=D-109%203rd%20floor%20ShakarPur%20Laxmi%20Nagar%20New%20Delhi%20110092&sensor=false

so I can get Response please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: params is a String..., what means that is a varargs (an array of Strings), not a String, so you have to access to your url which is stored in the first position by using params[0]

Comment: Do like this:
 response = GecodeFuncation.getLatLongByURL("your url" +params[0]+"&sensor=false");

let everything remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

execute task same like this:

response =

```
GecodeFuncation.getLatLongByURL("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+params[0]+"&sensor=false");
```